# Is free camping permitted in the Faroe Islands?

Tags: legal, planning, camping, faroe-islands

I'm planning to go to the Faroe Islands next August after visiting Iceland.

I was wondering if camping out in the wild is permitted anywhere in the Faroe Islands. I don't mind about the costs, but I just like the solitude and the idea of pitching your tent wherever you want.

Do I need to have a permit to sleep with a tent next to the road or in the fields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [FaroeIslands.com](http://www.faroeislands.com/default.aspx?pageid=9823):

> 1. Camping There are no public wilder­ness or common areas in the Faroes. As a consequence, camping is only permitted at designated
>      camp­sites (See page 88). Moreover, it is not permitted to stay
>      overnight in your camp­ing cars along the road, at rest stops, lay-bys
>      or view areas. Be aware that many camping sites are de­signated only
>      for tents. Cam­p­ers ought to be considerate of the environ­­ment,
>      keep the camp­ing areas tidy and clean up tho­roughly upon departure.
>      Be­cause of the unpredictable weather even in summer, it is advisable
>      to have sturdy, water­proof and windproof camping equipment. Fuel for
>      camping stov­es is available at petrol stations.

So no, wild or free camping is not permitted - you have to use designated campsites.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Mayo's answer is correct, however you may of course ask landowners if you can camp on their property. This is unlikely to happen often, so even if the answer is no, it is unlikely to be a hostile no.

I remember a blog with some Danes who did this and the landowner thought it quite amusing, rather.